# Define "sum" for a class using non-associative addition

Tags: python, oop

Is there something like a `__sum__` method, similar to `__add__`, in order to sum up a list of instances of classes into a new class instance?

I need this because in my case `sum([a,b,c])` should be different from `sum([sum([a,b]), c])`. In other words, the sum really depends on an arbitrary number of arguments, and cannot be defined in terms of a binary operation `__add__`.

Comment: can you please add a class definition to the post?

Comment: If your operation is not associative, maybe it should not be called `+` / `sum`.

Comment: No, you can't hook into what `sum` does. It just iterates over the container and invokes `__add__`, it doesn't have separate behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, this seems to be the answer to my question.

Comment: Remarkably similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60490938/12299000) which asks *What method, if any, is used when calling sum()?* But if your operation is not associative then why are you trying to use the built-in function `sum` for it?

Answer (score 31):

Summing will not work if you just define `__add__` because as [this](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/modifying-add-method-of-python-class.html) explains, the `sum` function starts with the integer `0`, and `0 + YourClass` will be undefined.

So, you need to define `__radd__` as well. Here's an implementation that will allow you to sum:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return self
    else:
        return self.__add__(other)
```

Now your class should be able to sum just fine.

EDIT:
(I'm aware that this does not solve OP's problem, but it solves the problem that people come to this question to solve, so I'm leaving it.)

Comment: Or just call it like `sum(..., start)` to provide an appropriate identity element.

Comment: I've seen this comment multiple times over the years, and never understood it, but just understood it today. If I'm right, you're saying that if you're summing up a list like `sum([obj1, obj2, obj3])`, and it's not working, you could add a neutral object to the start of the list where addition is defined, like `sum([Obj(0, 0, 0), obj1, obj2, obj3])`.

Answer (score -2):

`sum` is a built-in function in Python. `__add__` is a special method. Every container object such as list has an `__add__` method. You can see it in the [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). The `__add__` methods in container objects and numeric objects work differently.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

# Concatenation using .__add__()
print(l.__add__(b))
```

The result will be the concatenation of two lists,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

while the `__add__` method in numeric objects will do the addition operation.

```
x = 2
y = 3

# addition operation: 2 + 3 = 5
print(x.__add__(y))
```

You can create a custom list with a `sum` method.

```
class Custom(list):
    # adding sum() functionallity
    def sumup(self):
        return sum(self)
```

Create new custom list object like this,

```
l = Custom([1, 2, 3])
```

and call the sumup method to sum all values inside the custom list

```
l.sumup()
```

Comment: read the question again. I think you misunderstood what OP wants

Comment: "_the add method will invoked whenever '+' signs is presented_", no: [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)