# Why a class that can be added to itself can't be summed? (a+a works, sum([a,a]) fails)

Tags: python

In the following snippet, I create a Counter object and I try add it to itself using three ways. Standard addition using '+', reducing from a list (internally does the same as previous) and using the function sum() from a list.

The first 2 work and return the expected result, but the third raises a TypeError exception.

From here I have two questions:

1. What's the reason for the sum() failing if the addition works?
2. When I add to objects with +, the __ add__ method of the class is used. What method, if any, is used when calling sum()?

Counter is only an example, I'm interested on the general case rather than this one in particular for when I create new classes.

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
a = Counter([1,1,1,1])

print(a+a+a)
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [a,a, a]))
sum([a, a, a])
```

prints:

```
Counter({1: 12})
Counter({1: 12})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(sum([a, a,]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `sum([a, a])` is not doing `a + a`; it is actually doing `0 + a + a`. The `Counter` class instances can be added to instances of `Counter`, but they cannot be added to the integer `0`.

Think about how you'd write the `sum` function yourself:

```py
def sum(lst):
    total = 0
    for x in lst:
        total += x
    return total
```

In principle you could initialise `total = lst[0]` and then iterate over `lst[1:]` to add the remaining values. The problem with that is, then you can't get the sum of an empty sequence. So Python's actual `sum` function is like the code above, **except** you can specify the starting value ([docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)), so it's actually more like this:

```py
def sum(lst, start=0):
    total = start
    for x in lst:
        total = total + x
    return total
```

That means that for the behaviour you want, you can do `sum([a, a], Counter())`, because an "empty" `Counter` serves the same role as `0` does for adding numbers.

Note that it's like `total = total + x` and not `total += x`, because these can have different meanings for classes like `list`. In the general case, your class needs an [additive identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity) to use as the starting value for `sum`; if there is no suitable value for the "identity", you should use `reduce` instead.

Comment: Great answer! The documentation also provides some details: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! In the documentation I saw the 'start defaults to 0' bit but my brain didn't comprehend what that actually meant.